# Titanium - Dumping an object to the console

Tags: debugging, view, android-actionbar, stack, appcelerator

** update / workaround ** : I had to get this pushed live, so I've removed the action bar navigation module I was using and simply use the default android navigation and hardware back button and it works.

---

I have an app that is using some stack operations for Navigation.
iOS works perfectly, but in Android if I get 3 views deep, when I tap the action bar arrow to go back, it crashes with

```
[WARN] :   W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.hasProperty(KrollProxy.java:531)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties(TiUITableView.java:167)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:1173)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:513)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:504)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:482)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:520)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:504)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:482)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:520)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:504)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:482)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleAdd(TiViewProxy.java:692)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.add(TiViewProxy.java:585)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:62)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:872)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1095)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:360)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [7825,17084] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,17084] - In ti:/view.js:22,8
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,17084] - Message: Uncaught Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,17084] - Source:       _add.call(this, child);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/view.js:22: Uncaught Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

During my attempts at debugging, the problem occurs when its poping views off the stack.  I have an object called stack and I'd like to dump that to the console so I can look at what is in it, or if it is indeed empty.

I've tried `Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(stack))` but that results in a serialization error.

Any idea how I can dump the stack object or view what it contains at a specific point?

Comment: can you share some more code?

Comment: and please show the full error message. Normally it will show some java files where the null reference happened. That can give some clues on where the error is. Does the window that will lead to the crash contain a ScrollableView?

Comment: I've included the error dump, as well as the warning before hand.  My post wasn't really to have you all figure out my issue, I was more curious how to dump my stack object so I could verify it was ok. What is the best way to include a lot of code. Things are kind of spread out across multiple files.

Comment: This is a conference app, so I navigate from slide menu -> Session day list (table view) -> That day's sessions (tableview) -> session details (single screen).  The app crashes when I click back from the session details.  There are no scrollable views on either the session list or details screen.